How do I cross compile vcpkg packages on Linux for Windows?
I am looking to use a Linux machine to use vcpkg to install and export packages for use by a Windows machine.
Steps on the Linux machine:

Clone VCPKG
vcpkg install openssl --triplet=x64-windows-static
vcpkg export --zip openssl --triplet=x64-windows-static

This creates the exported package, but the created library files are .a when I need .lib files to be created.
The x64-windows-static triplet is setup as:
set(VCPKG_TARGET_ARCHITECTURE x64)
set(VCPKG_CRT_LINKAGE dynamic)
set(VCPKG_LIBRARY_LINKAGE static)
set(VCPKG_CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(OPTIONS_CROSS " --target-os=msvc --arch=x86_64")

Am I understanding how this cross compiling of vcpkg works, is my triplet file setup wrong, is this even possible?

The conclusion to this was to just avoid cross compiling at all costs, too many packages can fail to build in different ways.
